# Remove file name extension

Tags: java, android, file

In my android app I have filename like  `myfile.jpg.des`. I want to trim `.des` from filename. The final filename should be `myfile.jpg`. How to do in java/android

Thanks

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: use string.replace(old,new) ex string.replace(".des"," ");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
String test =  "myfile.jpg.des";
test = test.substring(0, test.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File from = new File(sdcard,"myfile.jpg.des");
 File to = new File(sdcard,"myfile.jpg");
 from.renameTo(to);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) to eliminate the file suffix:

```
String test =  "myfile.jpg.des";
test = test.replace(".des", "");
```